# Reference every resource created using for_each loop

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm creating a number of s3 buckets using for_each, and while the resources are being created with no issue. I'm having trouble referencing those resources later on. I'd like to be able to refer all of the resources. Like so:

````
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "dm_client" {
    for_each = toset(var.dm_client_bucket)

    bucket = format("dm-%s-%s",var.env,each.value)
    acl = "private"

    versioning {
        enabled = true
    }
...
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "dm_permission_client" {
    statement {
        sid = "ClientAccess"
        actions = [
            "s3:List*",
            "s3:Get*"
        ]
        resources = [
            aws_s3_bucket.dm_internal["*"].arn,
            "${aws_s3_bucket.dm_internal["*"].arn}/*",
            aws_s3_bucket.dm_client["*"].arn,
            "${aws_s3_bucket.dm_client["*"].arn}/*"
        ]
    }
}```
I've tried using *, "*", etc.. To no avail..
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `for_each` the resource value becomes a map from your keys to objects representing the resource instances. The `[*]` operator is for lists, so it doesn't work in this situation.

Instead, you can write a [`for` expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#for-expressions):

```
[for b in aws_s3_bucket.dm_internal : b.arn]
```

In the situation you are describing you need a list, but a similar syntax can also derive a map from keys to ARN strings:

```
{ for k, b in aws_s3_bucket.dm_internal : k => b.arn }
```

The `[*]` operator (["Splat Expressions"](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#splat-expressions)) is a shorthand for a `for` expression when applied to a list or set.

---

The `resources` argument in `aws_iam_policy_document` requires a list of strings, but if you were to just use `for` expressions directly there you'd get a list of lists of strings instead. To get the flat list of strings that argument is expecting, use [`concat`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/concat.html):

```
  resources = concat(
    [for b in aws_s3_bucket.dm_internal : b.arn],
    [for b in aws_s3_bucket.dm_internal : "${b.arn}/*"],
    [for b in aws_s3_bucket.dm_client : b.arn],
    [for b in aws_s3_bucket.dm_client : "${b.arn}/*"],
  )
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Unfortunately when I use your example. It returns an error Error creating IAM policy dm-dev-service-policy: MalformedPolicyDocument: Resource dm-dev-job must be in ARN format or "*".

Comment: It sounds like at least one of the S3 bucket ARNs is not in the format this configuration was expecting. If you run `terraform plan` and look for what JSON object is being proposed for the bucket policy on that resource you should be able to see there what ARNs this is generating and make sure all of them have valid syntax. I'm not super familiar with S3 ARN structure, but my initial guess would be that perhaps the `arn` attribute already has a path portion and so appending `/*` to the end might be making an invalid result.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I actually realized that using your example would reference buckets that aren't the s3 bucket that the policy is creating resulting in invalid resources.